# ¿Cómo corregir una pregunta con demasiado código?

Tags: soporte, preguntas, meta

No me deja introducir un código largo me dice que hay demasiadas líneas de código o me dice que no hay suficiente texto explicativo. ¿Me podríais decir cómo poder poner el código de la forma que estipula la web?
La cuestion es que parametros tengo que poner para que me deje intorucir un codigo.

Comment: Estimado, favor pon el código o pantallazo del error para poder identificar correctamente el error y te sugiero que cambies el título a algo relacionado con tu duda, para no confundir en las ventanas de inicio

Comment: Para resolver este problema debes reducir el código compartido. No hay una solución concreta, lo que debes hacer es no poner todo el código de tu proyecto, sólo la parte necesaria para reproducir el problema. Si necesitas más de los 30.000 caracteres permitidos en una pregunta, eso suele ser una señal de que algo no está bien (normalmente el código no es mínimo). Lee sobre [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](/help/mcve) para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: ok alvaro ya entiendo voy a leerme el enlace que me pones , para mas conociemiento del tema.